# Incorrect url generated by URL.Action and Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "NewsRoute",
    "News/{newsId}/{newsTitle}",
    new {
        controller = "News",
        action = "News",
        newsId = UrlParameter.Optional,
        newsTitle = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

and usage:

```
@Url.Action("News", "News", new { newsId = "", newsTitle = "" })
```

I want to have "/News" url, but instead "/News/News" is being generated. Default route is used I guess.
So the question is why NewsRoute is skipped?

Comment: looks like 2 optional paratemers forbidden to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to split route with 2 optional parameters and action to two separate actions:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "NewsRoute",
    "News", new {
        controller = "News",
        action = "Index"
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Specific News",
    "News/{id}/{title}",
    new {
        controller = "News",
        action = "News",
        title = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```